# ConnectivityManager getActiveNetworkInfo() returns null

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a function checking if there is a network connection available and I noticed it's crashing for some users. This is the function:

```
public static boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) RouteForMeApplication.getInstance()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectionManager == null) return false;
    boolean networkAvailable = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    return networkAvailable;
}
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.route4me.routeoptimizer.utils.InternetUtils.isOnline(InternetUtils.java:14)
   at com.route4me.routeoptimizer.services.notes.SendNoteServiceDeferred.sendNote(SendNoteServiceDeferred.java:57)
   at com.route4me.routeoptimizer.services.notes.SendNoteServiceDeferred.performAction(SendNoteServiceDeferred.java:28)
   at com.route4me.routeoptimizer.services.AbstractService$2.run(AbstractService.java:75)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

What I don't understand is why is it still returning null even though I'm checking if getActiveNetworkInfo() is not null. Any ideas?

**EDIT1**
The error is on the line "&& connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();"

Comment: Which is line no 14 in your InternetUtils.java class?

Comment: This line "&& connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();"

Answer (score 6):

Could easily be a race condition. It is not safe to assume that if `connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null` is true it will be true again one nanosecond later.

Rewrite it like this:

```
public static boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) RouteForMeApplication.getInstance()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectionManager == null) {
        return false;
    }
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()
    if (networkInfo == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but you still can't do this.  If the .getInstance() comes back null, then the .getSystemService is going to fail.  You would need to just get the ConnectionActivityManager, check it its not null.  If it is then return false.  If not, then call getSystemService.

Comment: Agree with the solution, but maybe the cause is not a race. We have been seeing two such crashes in our app, one in our own code and one in the Firebase analytics library, in both cases adjacent calls to getActiveNetworkInfo, only the second apparently returning null. We are getting a large number of such crashes. On the face of it that's extremely unlucky unless calling that function has a lazily-applied side-effect. Only seen in Android 7 and later, on different device manufacturers/types.

Comment: The problem is `connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()
`, it may produce NPE, simply checking for Null won't fix it. The only solution I forced to apply is to wrap it in try catch block.

Answer (score 0):

To access the connectivity manager you need to add the permission in the **Manifest** file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: I have that permission.

Comment: can you post your full logcat error and what is the getInstance() method you are using

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean CheckNetWorkState() {
        final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr == null)
            return false;

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
    }
```